# Complex Analysis - goniometric Contour Integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, laurent-series

I'm trying to solve that contour complex integral:

## **$\int\frac{1}{z^2sin(z)}$**

Over $|z|=4$

Since I was not able to find the Residue directly I tried to expand Laurent around **$z=0$.**

$\frac{1}{z^2sin(z)}=\frac{1}{z^2(z-\frac{1}{3!}z^3)}=...=\frac{1}{z^3}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{z^3}{36}+...$

So can I conclude that The residue is 0 (and so the integral) since the term $n(-1)$ does not exist?

Comment: If you have computed the Laurent series expansion correctly, then you can conclude that $\int f(z)\, dz = 0$.

Comment: That's not what I get for the Laurent series...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown could you post what you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get:

$$\frac1{z^2}\frac1{z-\frac{z^3}6+\ldots}=\frac1{z^3}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{z^2}6+\ldots}=\frac1{z^3}\left(1+\frac{z^2}6+\ldots\right)=\ldots\frac1{6z}$$

and the residues is $\;\cfrac16\;$ .